# Is React Query feasible for caching data in a chat application?

Tags: reactjs, caching, frontend, chat, react-query

In the chat app that I'm working on, switching between rooms fetches the messages of the selected chat room **every time**. However, if I had to implement caching, would React Query be suitable to cache the messages?

Still exploring other options

Answer (score 0):

React query can be used to cache received messages.
Paginated queries can be helpful: https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/guides/paginated-queries.

However, what about live data e.g. messages received in not selected chat rooms?
You probably want to show some unread indicator, so you need to know when a new message arrives.

To manage a chat state in React you can try a dedicated library: https://github.com/chatscope/use-chat
Using this lib, you can connect any source of messages, and the messages are kept (cached) in the memory.